# What does property-ref is dong here?

Tags: hibernate

There is this mapping table in my project,which I am unable to understand

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hasa.HeadOfState" table="headofstate">
    <id name="id" type="int">
    <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="title"/>
    <property name="name"/>
    <one-to-one name="con" class="hasa.country" property-ref="hos"></one-to-one>
    </class >
    <class name="hasa.country" table="country121">
 <id name="id" type="int">
 <generator class="increment"/>
 </id>   
 <property name="name"/>
<many-to-one name="hos" unique="true" class="hasa.HeadOfState" column="hostid" cascade="all"></many-to-one>    
 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

here my question is how does this property-ref="hos" is doing? 
also how does the primary key of headofstate class is added to the column hostid?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) Hope this helps

> the name of a property of the associated class that is joined to this foreign key. If not specified, the primary key of the associated class is used.